# Show Firebase data as Json in browser Console

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help to show my data from my Firebase database as JSON to browser console log.[image] I want load only `Product` into browser console. I found a code for pushing data from [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_FlX41qADE). Can anyone help me figure out the function please?

```js
var firebase = require('firebase');
//var admin = require('firebase-admin');

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx"
})
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Product');

//it's child directory
var messageRef = ref.child('/');


/*messageRef.push
({
    prdName: 'node1',
    prdCategory: 'node1',
    prdSup: 'node1',
    prdDescription: 'node1',
    prdImage: 'test1.jpg',
    prdUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ng-product.appspot.com/o/Uploads%2Ftest1.jpg?alt=media&token=f105332a-02c8-46ca-a639-745eda0e118c'

})*/

console.log('Product');
```

Comment: `json.stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from Firebase, you attach a listener. To then print it to the browser console, you call `console.log()` in the callback:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Product');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I highly recommend that you send some time reading the [Firebase Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), and take the corresponding [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). A few hours spent in those will save many more hours down the line.